# Isomorphism of invariants and coinvariants over a field

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, homological-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group with normal subgroup $N$ acting on a vector space $V$ over a field $k$ in which the order of $N$ is invertible. Denote $H:=G/N$. The composite map $V^N \to V \to V_N$ and $\frac 1 {|N|} \mathrm{Nm}$ are $H$-equivariant inverses of each other.

I am sort of surprised by this basic result. At the level of vector spaces, the constructed maps are canonical. But say we take $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and $V=M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}$ where $M$ is a free abelian group of finite rank. Then in bases modulo torsion of $M^N$ and $M_N$, the map $V^N\to V_N$ has a determinant which is well-defined up to sign. This determinant will not in general be $\pm 1$, some there is some sort of non-canonicity going on.

Is there some sort of high-level explanation that could motivate why this result is to be expected ?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking. The result is true over a field, not true over a ring. I have a sneaking suspicion that for whichever precise question you may ask, the answer will be obvious. For now, I do not think this post contains a precise question.

Comment: The map from invariants to coinvariants exists over any ring, it is canonical and is compatible with base change. The determinant not being $\pm 1$ just reflects the result not being true over rings.

Comment: How do you define the determinant of a homomorphism which is not an endomorphism?